# How to do subqueries with Kohana ORM v2.x

Tags: orm, subquery, kohana-db

How can i write the following query using Kohana ORM v 2.x?

```
 select k.* from kingdomprojects k
   where region_id in 
   ( select id from regions where kingdom_id = 1)"
```

Are subqueries are not supported in kohana v2.x ORM?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to do a plain-old regular query.

In Kohana 3, you could ask the result to be an object and give the name of your ORM model, like so:

```
->as_object('company')
```

[Kohana 3 Database documentation: subqueries](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/database/query/builder#subqueries)